# Images broken - out of options

Tags: cpanel

I've uploaded my site cpanel, (I zipped the files and then extracted them in cpanel - public_html) however after uploading some of images are broken.

i changed file extensions from.JPG to .jpg, but thats made no difference. file paths are correct.

?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1:

Please check the path that you have give to the images. If the path is incorrect then please modify it to the correct path and then refresh and try again.

## Option 2:

Try changing the permission of the folder in which you have uploaded these images to "777". Once the above to options have been done, try refreshing the page and check if the problem gets resolved.

**Newly Edited Answer:**

Can you please try adding the image paths as below:

```
<img src="../images/img_slides/logo1.jpg" alt="#" title="#home_slider_bottom_1" />
<img src="../images/img_slides/sld2.jpg" alt="#" title="#home_slider_bottom_2" />
<img src="../images/img_slides/sld3.jpg" alt="#" title="#home_slider_bottom_3" />
<img src="../images/img_slides/sld4.jpg" alt="#" title="#home_slider_bottom_4" />
```

This also depends on the folder structure. Can you please try adding the image path as above and also provide the folder structure where you have uploaded these images?

Comment: please have a look at my edited question, I've added the file paths. Please can you tell me if this is correct or not, as I'm not sure what it is supposed to be. Thank you

Comment: My images folder is in the main website folder, such as the following: /website/images/img_slide/logo1.jpg  Thats how it is on my pc, and in cpanel I transferred them all the same, in to the public_html folder.